# How to find data of two sum row in MySQL using CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.X and the issue is.......
In my Order table consider two fields 
1. descount_amount
2. total

And I saw in backend total amount and also give a search field in Ajax table.
and backend total amount is SUM of this two fields descount_amount + total.

My CakePHP filter code (search code is below)

```
if (isset($this->request->data['CouponHistory']['order_amount']) && $this->request->data['CouponHistory']['order_amount'] != '') {

            $this->Order = ClassRegistry::init('Order');
            $this->Order->virtualFields = array('total_amount' => 'SUM(Order.discount_amount+Order.total)');
            $order_id = $this->Order->find('list',array(
                   'contain' => array(),
                   'fields' => array('Order.id'),
                   'conditions' => array("Order.total_amount LIKE" => '%'.$this->request->data['CouponHistory']['order_amount'].'%'),
                   //'group' => 'Order.id'
                ));
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($order_id); die;    
            $condition[] = array("CouponHistory.order_id" => $order_id);
        }
```

How to Search this type data in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

U can make two changes to make it work.

1. No need to use LIKE in your condition array for what i think total_amount is a numeric value.
2. There is no use to create virtual field total_amount. you can calculate sum in the condition itself.

so you condition will look something like this:

'conditions' => array(
        'sum(Order.discount_amount Order.total)' => $this->request->data['CouponHistory']['order_amount'] )